# React state array (first input not working)

Tags: reactjs, state

why I can't set the Data in the first Click I Have to input twice to set the data.
Thanks for your help...

```
export default function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState();
  const [projectData, setProjectData] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setProjectData([...projectData, { projectTitle: title }]);
    console.log(projectData);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setTitle(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>insert</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are setting the data, the `console.log()` is just outputting the old data as `setState` is asyncronous and `projectData` hasn't changed yet.

Comment: To see what happens in real time, just append this somewhere in the page `{JSON.stringify(projectData)}`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it did, but the `setState` hook runs asynchronously so the `console.log` after that won't reflect the change. You could use `useEffect` to watch for the change of `projectData` instead

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState();
  const [projectData, setProjectData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(projectData);
  }, [projectData]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setProjectData([...projectData, { projectTitle: title }]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setTitle(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>insert</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit red-leaf-lez7s]

Answer (score 0):

In React setState actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains. This is explained in the documentation of setState.
If you want to log `projectData` you can use `useEffect` hook.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setProjectData([...projectData, { projectTitle: title }]);
};
  
// useEffect with ProjectData as dependency 
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(projectData);
}, [projectData]);
```